# jQuery function not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cross-browser

i have following Jquery Script to hide and show a button, depending upon the class of the li tag it is in

```
$('li#test').each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass('active'))
        {
            //Active class is applied
            $(this).children().children().closest("img").attr("src", "assets/img/button_home_selected3.png");
            $(this).children().children().closest("button").css("display","table");
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).children().children().closest("img").attr("src", "assets/img/button_home_plain1.png");
            $(this).children().children().closest("button").css("display","none");
        }
    });
```

By default the button tag has display:none.

The html is:

```
<ul id="nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
  <li id="test" style="list-style: none;" class="active">
   <a href="#home" data-toggle="tabs" ><img src="assets/img/button_home_selected3.png" id="test2"  width="83"/><span>Home</span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

the li tags are dynamically added using script

```
$('.plus').click(function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 var li_count = $('#nav-tabs').length;
 if (li_count <= 3){
  if(counter <= 3){
   $('#nav-tabs').append('<li id="test" ><a href="#tab' + counter + '" data-toggle="tabs" ><img src="assets/img/button_home_plain1.png" width="83" id="test2">Tab' + counter + '</span><button type="button" class="close">&times;</button></a></li>');
} else { alert("Only 3 Tabs Allowed!")};
}
```

also there is one active tag which toggles between the tabs, which is done using script

```
$('li#test').each(function() {
if($(this).hasClass('active'))
 {//Active class is applied
  $(this).children().children().attr("src", "assets/img/button_home_selected3.png");
 }
 else
 {
  $(this).children().children().attr("src", "assets/img/button_home_plain.png");
 }
```

});

This is working fine for IE and firefox, but not in Google Chrome...

Comment: Can you confirm that the specific element(s) get the correct style (`display:table`) with Developer Tools? If so, then we can know it's purely a CSS problem and not something weird happening with the jQuery

Comment: Can you show your html? Use jsfidle.com to help demonstrate your example.

Comment: Using `children().children().closest()` just doesn't look right to me because `closest()` looks at self and parents, what does your HTML look like?

Comment: using chrome DOM inspector, if i change the display to anything after the page loads i.e any property, other than the current property, it is visible, other than that it doesn't matter if the display has none, table, table-captions, block; it just wont show...

Comment: There must be some browser compatibility issue with chrome, because it is the only browser not showing, i was extecting this sort of stuff from IE :p

Comment: Is your code wrapped in a document ready function? `$(function(){...});`? Also, don't use the same ID for every list item; use a class name instead.

Comment: YES! it is in document.ready....

Comment: ok, done that, now can you tell me what i asked for ... why is this not working on Chrome

Comment: Try using `$(this).find('img')` instead of `$(this).children().children().closest("img")`. And change the id's into class names.

Comment: this will also change other img tags and button tags, which i dont want to change, and i have changed the id into classes still the same result

Comment: Well, at this point it would be better if you set up a basic demo of your code. Try http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. Id's should be unique. So change your HTML to this:

   ```
   <ul id="nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
     <li class="test active" style="list-style: none;">
      <a href="#home" data-toggle="tabs" >
       <img src="assets/img/button_home_selected3.png" class="test2" width="83"/> 
       <span>Home</span>
      </a>
     </li>
   </ul>
   ```

   the javascript:

   ```
   $('li.test').each(function() {
     if($(this).hasClass('active'))
     {
       //Active class is applied
       $(this).find("img").attr("src", "assets/img/button_home_selected3.png");
       $(this).find("button").show();
     }
     else
     {
       $(this).find("img").attr("src", "assets/img/button_home_plain1.png");
       $(this).find("button").hide();
     }
   });
   ```
2. Get the length of the `li`'s, not the `ul`:

   ```
   $('.plus').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var li_count = $('#nav-tabs').find('li').length;
     if (li_count <= 3){
       if(counter <= 3){
         $('#nav-tabs').append('<li class="test"><a href="#tab' + counter + '" data-toggle="tabs" ><img src="assets/img/button_home_plain1.png" width="83" class="test2">Tab' + counter + '</span><button type="button" class="close">&times;</button></a></li>');
       } else {
         alert("Only 3 Tabs Allowed!")
       }
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: i know there are issues with the code, and have corrected most of them as i have mentioned earlier, but please answering my first and foremost question, Everything is working fine; except in Google Chrome

Comment: can anyone answer this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14907997/show-dynamically-added-navlinks-when-added-in-bootstrap-navbar

Answer (score 0):

I Got the answer, with some researching, it appears Google Chrome wont do hide and show on any other tags than div and span, as my button tag was not inside any div or span tag, thus it was not performing the operation on Chrome...

Comment: Not sure where you are getting your information, but it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/8akKH/